# Tabitem PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown is raised every time when mouse is pressed to the inside content. How to avoid this?

Tags: wpf, mouseevent, tabitem

In WPF, I have raised `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` for a `TabItem`.  I want this event to raise when `TabItem`'s header is clcked. The `TabItem`'s content is a `TextBox` and a `Button`, but whenever I click on the `TextBox` or `Button`, `TabItem`'s `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` is raised. How can it be avoided?

Please help,

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is due to tunneling in Wpf, you can stop tunneling by handling this event at root and in the handler write:

```
e.Handled = true;
```

then it will not tunnel down.

And then if you want to handle it for your textbox or button
use AddHandler method to assign handler to the event instead of using normal += format.

```
button.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnbuttonClick));
```

Check this for details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx#event_handing